# What is "validation set" and why is 0 and I try to write the formula for RMS and I get the error "ZeroDivisionError"

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, price

rms=np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power((np.array(valid['price'])-preds),2)))

print('\n RMSE value on validation set:')

print(rms)

ZeroDividedError

## set validation set (0,232)

And the dataset is in following image
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq7Bp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "mean" argument size is zero, check arrays shapes.